# Install then run an npm package in github

Tags: node.js

It's 1 am and I'm tearing my hair out so I just want to know if this will work.

I'm trying to make a github action that installs an npm package, and then runs that package. So far, I have:

```
- run: npm install -g electron-iso-packager 
- run: sudo electron-iso-packager ./ FunnyApp
```

The package installs fine, but on the second command, I get:

```
 sudo: electron-iso-packager: command not found
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Try providing the full path to `electrion-iso-packager` in the second command.

Comment: What would that be? @TyHitzeman